# Transform nonlinear cost function to get LP or MILP

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, linearization, nonlinear-programming, matlab

I'm trying to schedule power of multiple prosumers in a microgrid.
The problem includes a cost function with `min` and `max` statements since I want to distinguish between the prices for importing and exporting energy.

The following is a minimal example for the cost function without summing over all timesteps at the moment:

I have two decision variables $P_{charge}$ and $P_{discharge}$ for the battery storage (one of it is assumed to be always zero) and one other controllable load $P_{load}$. Consumption is denoted with positive and generation with negative values. $C_{import}$ and $C_{export}$ are the per unit prices for importing and exporting energy.

$C = max((P_{charge} + P_{discharge} + P_{load}) \cdot \Delta T,0) \cdot C_{import} + min((P_{charge} + P_{discharge} + P_{load}) \cdot \Delta T,0) \cdot C_{export}$

The `min` and `max` functions form `if-else` statements to check if the sum of power flows is negative or positive.
Is it possible to introduce some binary decision variables to transform it into a MILP? I want to use a Matlab solver later.

Edit 1:

I have tried to introduce the proposed auxiliary variables but they do not match the desired values I computed from my simulation. So maybe I have to clarify the problem. At first, I simplify power flow of battery to one bidirectional power variable to reduce the problem further.

[image]

The image shows a part of my problem.
My objective is to maximize $R - C$, where $R \ge 0$ is revenue and $C \ge 0$ is cost. Per unit prices are always greater than or equal to zero and $C_{import} > C_{export}$ is valid for now. The nonlinear version would be:

$$R = min(P_{load} + P_{BSS},0) \cdot (-1) \cdot C_{export}$$
$$C = max(P_{load} + P_{BSS},0) \cdot C_{import}$$

I have defined non-negative decision variables $X_{import}$ and $X_{export}$ with the line capacity (energy per timestep) as upper boundary. Additionally I've introduced following equality constraint:

$$(P_{load} + P_{BSS}) \cdot \Delta T == X_{import} - X_{export}$$

I neglected the injected PV power at this node for now. My goal is to be somehow able to use the auxiliary variables for an upper level node.
Maybe I didn't fully understand the proposed answers which might led to the undesired result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking a different tack from Rob, I'm going to assume that the original objective function $C$ is correct as stated and is being minimized, with $C_\text{export}>0$ being a per-unit compensation value for exported energy (i.e., you pay to import and get paid to export). In that case, splitting the energy expression into $X_\text{import} - X_\text{export}$ as Rob does will work if $C_\text{import} > C_\text{export}$ but will not work with $C_\text{import} < C_\text{export},$ since in the latter case the solver could add an arbitrary amount $\delta > 0$ to both $X_\text{import}$ and $X_\text{export},$ keeping the energy value the same while reaping an undeserved profit of $(C_\text{export} - C_\text{import})\delta.$ In this case, you have to introduce a binary variable $Y$ and constraints $$X_\text{import}\le M_\text{import}\cdot Y$$ and $$X_\text{export}\le M_\text{export}\cdot (1-Y),$$ where $M_\text{import}$ and $M_\text{export}$ are upper bounds on the amount of energy that could be imported or exported.

Comment: Thanks you for the hint! I tried to implement this as well. The binary variable seemed to be only zero for every timestep. Do I have to include Y somehow into the objective function? Is M a fixed boundary like the line capacity or is it the maximum for every timestep based on the current power flow? But this would involve some abs functions I guess. Maybe my edited questions helps to clarify the problem.

Comment: $M$ is a constant. It can be indexed by time if you know a priori bounds on imports and exports for that time, but it is not intended to be dependent on the variables in the model. $Y$ does not belong in the objective. I assume that you actually have a $P_{load}$ variable etc. for each combination of prosumer and time step. Whatever the indexing of $P_{load}$ and its siblings, the $X$ and $Y$ variables would have the same indexing.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much! Now it works as intended. I assume that splitting $P_{BSS}$ into charging and discharging power can be treated the same way.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you meant $C=\max() - \min()$ instead of $C=\max() + \min()$,
you can introduce nonnegative variables
$X_\text{import}$ and $X_\text{export}$
and linear constraints
$$(P_\text{charge} + P_\text{discharge} + P_\text{load}) \cdot \Delta T = X_\text{import} - X_\text{export}$$
and then minimize the linear function
$$C_\text{import} X_\text{import} + C_\text{export} X_\text{export}.$$

Comment: +1 this. If the economics ($C_\text{import} > C_\text{export}$) are realistic, this will automatically lead to mutually exclusive charging/discharging decisions, completely without leaving the cosy LP space.

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you for your answer. I tried to implement it but the aux variables didn't match the desired values. I've edited my question to clarify the problem and my thoughts. I hope that helps!